# creating child process with MPI_Comm_spawn

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi, spawn

Can someone explain why even when I set the number of process to more than 1 only two process child are created in the code below. Each MPI_Comm_spawn can create two child process using the code below, in the code used each process created with mpirun will call MPI_Comm_spawn once and will create 2 (#define NUM_SPAWNS 2) child process, so if I call N process then childs 2*N process child must be created. But this does not happen.

In the example below the number of the children must be 4 * 2 = 8. But...

for example:

**:~$ mpirun -np 4 ./spawn_example**

output:

I'm the parent.

I'm the parent.

I'm the parent.

I'm the parent.

I'm the spawned.

I'm the spawned.

[The following sample code illustrates MPI_Comm_spawn.](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Comm_spawn.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what `MPI_Comm_spawn` does. It is a collective call and it does not spawn `n` additional processes per rank but rather it spawns a child MPI job with `n` processes, therefore adding `n` to the total number of processes. When called with `n = 2`, it spawn a child job with 2 processes and that's exactly what you observe in the output.

Comment: thank you so much! How could I create n processes child per rank (parent)? It is possible?

Comment: No, MPI doesn't have a concept of per-rank child processes. Even more, processes spawned with `MPI_Comm_spawn` could end up on a totally different set of CPUs (or cluster nodes) than the processes that were initially part of the MPI job. You could use `fork()` to start child processes per rank but that is non-standard and not supported by all MPI implementations (e.g. on Blue Gene/Q).

Answer (score 5):

As long as MPI_Comm_spawn is collective call you can use MPI_COMM_SELF to create children for that particular parent:

Parent:

```
// Child communicator
MPI_Comm child;
// spawn errors
int spawnError[N];
// Spawn 2 child process for each process
MPI_Comm_spawn("./child", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 2, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &child, spawnError);
// Broadcast world id for current parent process to children
int myid;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
MPI_Bcast(&myid,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ROOT,child);
```

Child:

```
// Obtain an intercommunicator to the parent MPI job
MPI_Comm parent;
MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent);
// Get child rank
int myid;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
// Check if this process is a spawned one and if so get parent CPU rank
if (parent != MPI_COMM_NULL) {
  int parent_id;
  MPI_Bcast(&parent_id, 1, MPI_INT,0, parent);
  std::cout<<"Child "<<myid<<" of Parent "<<parent_id<<std::endl;
}
```

The result will be:

```
> mpirun -np 4 parent
Child 0 of Parent 2
Child 0 of Parent 1
Child 0 of Parent 0
Child 0 of Parent 3
Child 1 of Parent 0
Child 1 of Parent 2
Child 1 of Parent 1
Child 1 of Parent 3
```

The only problem for this approach is that children of a different parent will never be able to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on comm parameter. If you use MPI_COMM_SELF then every master will create n processes, but if you use MPI_COMM_WORLD among all masters will create n processes. 
So if you have 2 masters in the first case you are gointg to create 2 * n processes. In the second case you are going to create n processes.